# itertools.imap manipulation Python 2

Tags: python, django, python-itertools

Context:

I have a Django server and the response object to a request is of type:

```
type(response) -> itertools.imap
```

I need to check the size using a custom method. The size check is successful but the response object, or maybe it's contents, get consumed/ emptied out even though my method doesn't alter it.

casting the response as a list:

```
list(response)
```

also consumes/ empties it - but the list if filled.

Question(s):

How do I get the contents of an itertools.imap without consuming/ emptying  it?

Can I turn the list back into an itertools.imap?

Comment: You cannot check the length of a generator without exhausting it. Just listify it?

Comment: @coldspeed thanks for the suggestion. I've tried to cast it to a list via `list(response)`  but it still gets emptied. How else do I listify it?

Comment: `l = list(response); print(l); for x in l: ...`

Comment: @coldspeed thanks what I meant was the itertools.imap gets emptied if I call list(response).

Comment: Yes, and I'm saying you can empty it and still use the list later. You can't have the cake and eat it too.

Comment: @coldspeed do you know how I could reconvert the list to an itertools.imap? I can't leave it empty as it needs to be returned as a response to the browser.

Comment: Well, you could look at `itertools.tee` which returns two separate copies of the same iterator. Use the first to check the length, and the second to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [itertools.imap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) and will be consumed whatever action you do on it.

Unfortunately, you cannot convert it back to imap, but if you need an iterator, you can create it from your list.

```
l = list(response)
new_response = iter(l)
```

Or you can make a copy of your iterator with [tee](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap)

However, in most of the cases, a list is enough

> In general, if one iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts, it is faster to use list() instead of tee().

As mentioned in the comments, the code should not care about the type of the object (`list` or `imap`), as the code iterates over it indifferently

Comment: This is actually one of my original implementation to this problem but the response returned wasn't the one I expected. Turns out there was a different problem, as I did some separate testing with this code, but kudos to you for coming up with a great answer and explanation!

Comment: Note: `itertools.imap` **is not a generator**. Also, you can trivially create an equialent `imap` object, just use `itertools.imap(lambda x:x, l)`, but the important point is *the code shouldn't care if you are passing an `itertools.imap` object or a `list` object, because they can both be iterated over in the exact same way and give you equivalent results*